# getting the distance and time in google map and direction

Tags: php, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-api-2

I'm working on a simple taxi fare calculating program using google map get directions from google map.

So here's the code:

HTML(map.php)

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Demo GPS plugin</title>
<style>
    #map {
        width: 500px;
        height: 200px;
    }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=2&amp;sensor=true&amp;key=AIzaSyC7DlktbkGzLS0dvYqRJaGtbXG6mmoGUhA" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="gps.jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {

$("#map").googleMap().load();

});
</script>
</head>
<body onunload="GUnload()">
    <div id="directions"></div>
    <div id="map"></div>

    <form action="directions.php" method="post">
        <p><b>From: </b><input id="start" type="text"/>
        <b>To: </b><input id="end" type="text" /></p>
        <input name="submit" id="getdirections" type="submit" value="Get Directions" />
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

JQUERY code:

```
(function($) {

    $.GoogleMapObjectDefaults = {        
        zoomLevel: 14,
    imagewidth: 50,
    imageheight: 50,
    start: '#start',
        end: '#end',
    directions: 'directions',
        submit: '#getdirections',
    tooltip: 'false',
    image: 'false'
    };

    function GoogleMapObject(elementId, options) {
        /* private variables */
        this._inited = false;
        this._map = null;
        this._geocoder = null;

        /* Public properties */
        this.ElementId = elementId;
        this.Settings = $.extend({}, $.GoogleMapObjectDefaults, options || '');
    }

    $.extend(GoogleMapObject.prototype, {
        init: function() {
            if (!this._inited) {
                if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {
                    this._map = new GMap2(document.getElementById(this.ElementId));
                    this._map.addControl(new GSmallMapControl());
                    this._geocoder = new GClientGeocoder();
                }

                this._inited = true;
            }
        },
        load: function() {
            //ensure existence
            this.init();

            if (this._geocoder) {
                //"this" will be in the wrong context for the callback
                var zoom = this.Settings.zoomLevel;
                var center = this.Settings.center;
        var width = this.Settings.imagewidth;
        var height = this.Settings.imageheight;
                var map = this._map;

        if (this.Settings.tooltip != 'false') {
            var customtooltip = true;
            var tooltipinfo = this.Settings.tooltip;
        }

        if (this.Settings.image != 'false') {
            var customimage = true;
            var imageurl = this.Settings.image;
        }

                this._geocoder.getLatLng(center, function(point) {
                    if (!point) { alert(center + " not found"); }
                    else {
                        //set center on the map
                        map.setCenter(point, zoom);

            if (customimage == true) {
                //add the marker
                var customiconsize = new GSize(width, height);
                var customicon = new GIcon(G_DEFAULT_ICON, imageurl);
                customicon.iconSize = customiconsize;
                var marker = new GMarker(point, { icon: customicon });
                map.addOverlay(marker);
            } else {
                var marker = new GMarker(point);
                map.addOverlay(marker);
            }

            if(customtooltip == true) {
                marker.openInfoWindowHtml(tooltipinfo);
            }
                    }
                });
            }


            //make this available to the click element
            $.data($(this.Settings.submit)[0], 'inst', this);

            $(this.Settings.submit).click(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var obj = $.data(this, 'inst');
        var outputto = obj.Settings.directions;
                var from = $(obj.Settings.start).val();
                var to = $(obj.Settings.end).val();
        map.clearOverlays();
        var gdir = new GDirections(map, document.getElementById(outputto));
        gdir.load("from: " + from + " to: " + to);

                //open the google window
                //window.open("http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=" + from + "&daddr=" + to, "GoogleWin", "menubar=1,resizable=1,scrollbars=1,width=750,height=500,left=10,top=10");
            });

            return this;
        }
    });

    $.extend($.fn, {
        googleMap: function(options) {
            // check if a map was already created
            var mapInst = $.data(this[0], 'googleMap');
            if (mapInst) {
                return mapInst;

            }


            //create a new map instance
            mapInst = new GoogleMapObject($(this).attr('id'), options);
            $.data(this[0], 'googleMap', mapInst);

            return mapInst;

        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

The user will input two different locations(from and to) then it will calculate distance and time.. Now, how can i get the values of distance and time so I can use it to calculate the fare?.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Your code is using the deprecated [Google Maps Javascript API v2](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/reference). You should upgrade to v3 ASAP.

Comment: how can i upgrade.?. can you show some tutorial. Please. I'm just a newbie in using javascript.

Comment: The very top of the documentation for v2 says the following and provides a [link to a migration guide](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/v2tov3): **Warning**: Version 2 of the Google Maps JavaScript API is no longer available. Please follow the guide to migrate your code to version 3 of the Google Maps JavaScript API. As of November 19, 2013, all applications requesting v2 are served a special, wrapped version of the v3 API instead. We strongly encourage you to migrate to the v3 API immediately.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [Distance Matrix API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distancematrix/). It can calculates times and distance between 2 (or more) points. Just take a look at [the samples](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/distancematrix)

Comment: I've already calculated the time and distance and show the result, it worked fine. But the problem is I can't get the value of distance and time. just like in Google map get direction: [link]https://maps.google.com/

Comment: @JaybeeJohnBalog What do you mean by "I've already calculated the time and distance" and "I can't get the value of distance and time"? Seems contradictory to me. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: I mean code works fine in outputting the results time and distance plus the other results.. but it seems all the results are like in a one <div> and i just wanna only catch the value of time and distance.. Please see this example..[link] http://www.birdwingfx.com/jQuery_gps/demo_gps/gps_demo.html